# var return to NaN instead of number

Tags: javascript

Hey so i've something like that

```
var zxc1 = 1846;
var zxc2 = 1649;
var zxc3 = 174;
var zxc4 = 27;

if(message.toLowerCase() == ('!asd')) { client.say(channel, `zxc1`  +`(${+ zxc1.toLocaleString()})` +` | zxc2 `+`(${+ zxc2.toLocaleString()})` +` | zxc3 ` +`(${+ zxc3.toLocaleString()})` +` | zxc4 ` +`(${+ zxc4.toLocaleString()})` +` | :) `);}
```

After typing !asd:

Result : `zxc1(NaN) | zxc2 (NaN) | zxc3 (174) | zxc4 (27) | 2`

what's the problem?

Why is zxc3 and zxc4 working but zxc1 and zxc2 no

Comment: Depending on your locale `1846.toLocaleString()` could be something like `1 846` which cannot be parsed to a number ...

Comment: Just remove the `+`, there's no point of using it since the number is going to be converted back to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `${+ zxc1.toLocaleString()}` the `+` will be applying on the result of `zxc1.toLocaleString()` to coerce it back to a number (which seems counterproductive).

If you are not sure if something is a number I do recommend you use the number function e.g. `${Number(zxc1).toLocaleString()}` rather than using `+`

The reason why 3 and 4 are working is because (most likely) your locale adds a thousands separator and so 1 and 2 are not castable back to numbers directly